# Is there HashSet which implements NavigableSet in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I need to parse some site for a list of users and their posts.
Users are represented by UserIds, and posts by PostIds, which are actually integers.
So I create a class for user like this:

```java
class User {
    private int userId;
    private List<Integer> postList;
    //...
}
```

And then I'm encountering a problem. 
This site provides an api, which returns a list of post structures like:

```java
class Post {
    int postId;
    int postAuthorId;
    String postText;
    //...
}
```

So I should get a post, search if I already have post author (user) in my user set, if no, add new user and post ids to user set, if yes - add post id to the list of this user posts.
Firstly I wanted to use `HashSet` - because of quick add and search methods. But then I realized that I can't get desired user from `HashSet`. Next I thought about `TreeSet`, which implements `NavigableSet`, so I can use `TreeSet.ceiling(user)`. It returns object, so I can modify it. It all is fine, but `HashSet` is much faster than `TreeSet`.
So the question is, if there is some kind of `HashSet` which can return specific objects, like if it was implementing `NavigableSet`?
Or I just should rewrite my code somehow? Will be grateful for ideas.

Comment: So you want to access the HashSet via the user?

Comment: is there a reason you wouldn't use a `HashMap` that maps the user ID to the User?

Comment: @Compass Thank you for good idea, I am new to practical use of collections and Map is really useful in my purpose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an extension to my comment, this sounds like a practical use of HashMap. You can use the user id in User as the key, and map to the User object. Using what you've given us, the below code would populate the users HashMap.

```
HashMap<Integer, User> users = new HashMap<>();

for(Post post : posts) {
    int userId = post.getPostAuthorId();
    if(users.get(userId) != null) {
        users.get(userId).addPost(post);
    }
    else {
        users.put(userId, new User(userId));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this suits the best! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The *reason* that `HashSet` is faster is that it's not sorted. A `NavigableSet` needs to be sorted, and any implementation will necessarily have some overhead in keeping the set ordered. `TreeSet` is probably the best general-purpose sorted-set implementation available, and if you need the features that `NavigableSet` brings, you'll need to pay the performance cost. I'm quite skeptical that the overhead in the set lookups is the sticking point in your program in any case.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) Javadoc,

*All Known Implementing Classes:*
   [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

And since a hash function destroys any kind of natural ordering I think a `NavigableSet` would be impossible with basic hashing.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably keep your list of Users and your list of posts separate.  Then use maps that suit your purposes to associate them.  If you use something like hibernate with it, you'll be able to keep using them as POJOs and get persistence out of it as well.

If you want to keep the posts inside the user you probably would also rewrite the Hash function of your `User` class so that the class would be ID'd by the userID alone and not the posts. (As well as rewriting `equals`)

Some more on that here [Why is the default hashcode() in java bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978026/why-is-the-default-hashcode-in-java-bad)